# Thumb from MOV on server IOS

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking, mov

I have this file .MOV on my server, and i need to display a thumbnail to the user before the video starts downloading.
I was thinking to use something with AFNetworking

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
```

but since the file is on .MOV, i have to first download it and then create the thumbnail...
Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. You prepare a thumbnail image that you place on the server. If the movie is called .MOV you can call the image .PNG for instance. So you can download the image before loading the movie.
2. You only store the .MOV, but you prepare a server side application that creates the image on the fly when the iOS device asks for the movie.

Option 1 seems more performant, and can be used for servers where you can only store data. Option 2 can be used for servers where users store their own movies, and where you can run server side applications.